# LSTM Autoencoder Keras variable batch size

Tags: lstm, keras

I have a collection of sequences.  I would like to encode them as vectors of length `encoded_dim`.  To that end, I made an autoencoder using stacked LSTMs in Keras:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(None, input_dim))

encoded = LSTM(encoded_dim)(LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True)(inputs))

decoded = RepeatVector(timesteps)(encoded)
decoded = Dense(8)(Dense(100)(LSTM(input_dim, return_sequences=True)(decoded)))

sequence_autoencoder = Model(inputs, decoded)

sequence_autoencoder.compile(optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01), loss='mean_squared_error')
sequence_autoencoder.fit(input, input, epochs=3000, batch_size=16, shuffle=False, callbacks=[...], validation_split=.2)
```

This works well when I restrict my attention to sequences of length `timesteps`.  In general, however, my sequences are not the same length, so `RepeatVector(timesteps)` won't work as is. (This will also mess up batching, but I have had decent training with `batch_size=1` so I'm not too worried about that for my particular use case.)

There is a fruitful conversation [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6776) involving variable length input sequences and batching, in the context of general seq2seq modeling.  Unfortunately, there is no concern there for retrieving the fixed size encoding.

Any suggestions/code snippets are greatly appreciated.